# How "onrendered" is used in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I have following code to take the screenshot of  'target'  division. I found this on a website. But I do not know how " onrendered:function() "  works. I want to ask how "onrendered" is used ? And what difference does it make if I do not add  " onrendered : " ?

```js
$('#target').html2canvas({
        onrendered: function (canvas)   
         {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");      
         } 
    });
```

Comment: Check out https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html

Comment: @DanielD what difference does it make if i do not add onrendered: part before function(canvas) ?

Comment: @DanielD your link is broken, you have to remove ".html" from the end of it

Comment: @nabi It simply doesn't work that way my friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
onrendered
```

Gets fired when the final canvas is done converting, and renders. So basically there's a very small amount of time between converting it from html to a canvas.

[Here's some documentation I found about html2canvas.](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html)

Comment: what difference does it make if i do not add onrendered: part before function(canvas) ?